# USER_ID indefinido en integración de CheckoutPro MercadoPago con Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, mercadopago

Integré Checkout Pro de MercadoPago a un proyecto de Laravel 8, cuando realizo pagos con credenciales de prueba en el proyecto local funciona todo correctamente, pero en producción al haber cambiado las credenciales de prueba por las credenciales activadas de producción me sale un error que el Index: id, está indefinido en el archivo MercadoPago/Config.php en la línea 113.

```
parent::set('USER_ID', $user['id']);
```

Básicamente esto ocurre después de darle al botón que redirecciona a los detalles del curso a vender, porque además de recopilar la información del curso a través del idcurso pasado en la ruta, en el controlador además es donde se invoca a mercadopago para crear la preferencia.

Esto es lo que tengo en ese controlador:

```
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken(env('MP_ACCESS_TOKEN'));
$public_key = env('MP_PUBLIC_KEY');
// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

// Urls de retorno

$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cursos/pago-completado/$id",
    "failure" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cursos/error-pago"
);

// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = $curso->nombre;
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = $curso->precio;
$item->id = $curso->id;
$item->currency_id = "ARS";
$preference->items = array($item);
$preference->binary_mode = true;
$preference->save();

return view('home.curso-detalle', compact('curso', 'seccion', 'preference', 'public_key'));
```

Y en la vista añado el script que muestra el boton:

```
<script src="https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2"></script>

<script>const mp = new MercadoPago('<?php echo $public_key ?>', {
    locale: 'es-AR'});
mp.checkout({
  preference: {
      id: '<?php echo $preference->id ?>'
  },
  render: {
        container: '.pagar', // Indica dónde se mostrará el botón de pago
        label: 'Comprar', // Cambia el texto del botón de pago (opcional)
  },theme: {
elementsColor: '#8e44ad'}}); </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución era ejecutar el siguiente comando en el servidor para que las variables del archivo env funcionaran correctamente de nuevo.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Al cambiar las variables de entorno, por alguna razón a veces se "rompen" y al querer acceder a ellas no devuelven nada, asi que con el comando de laravel de arriba se soluciona el problema.